# button not triggering as required

Tags: c#, javascript, webforms

My button is not automatically triggering, it works when I click it manually,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() { 

     $('#yes').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 

            $('<%= HiddenButton.ClientID %>').trigger('click');  // NOT Working
            __doPostBack('<%=HiddenButton.ClientID %>', '');     // THIS not working too
```

Button code is as given below. Both trigger and doPostBack didn't worked at all

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />    
    <asp:Button ID="HiddenButton" Text="Click Me" runat="server" OnClick="Deleting_Click" />
```

and also added trigger as,

```
   <triggers>
     <asp:asyncpostbacktrigger controlid="HiddenButton" eventname="Click" />
  </triggers>
```

I know I can check a value in page load method and then call method there but I want to do it using java script. Can somone direct me in right direction please

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net button works once and then stops working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339560/asp-net-button-works-once-and-then-stops-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
$('#<%= HiddenButton.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
```

You forgot the hashtag indicating you're targetting an id...

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

     $('#yes').click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
             clickTheButton();
            });
});

function clickTheButton() {
  document.getElementById('<%= HiddenButton.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a button click like this:

```
$('#yes').click();
```

assuming "yes" is the id of the button. Is this what you mean??